# Exception: TypeError(string indices must be integers)

Tags: python, json, exception, geojson

I have written the below python function (a snippet of the full code) to work in AWS Lambda. The purpose of it is to take a GeoJSON from an S3 bucket and parse it accordingly.

Once parsed, it is placed back into JSON format (`data`) and then should be inserted into the specified database using

```
        
                    bulk_item['uuid'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
                    bulk_item['name'] = feature_name
                    bulk_item['type'] = feature_type
                    bulk_item['info'] = obj
                    bulk_item['created'] = epoch_time
                    bulk_item['scope'] = 2

                    data = json.dumps(bulk_item)
                    print(data)
                    
           
                    self.database.upsert_record(self.organisation, json_doc=data)  

                
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception: {e.__class__.__name__}({e})')
```

The db_access file in which the above is relating to is another python script. The function `upsert_record` is as below:

```
def upsert_record(self, organisation,
        json_doc={}):
```

My code is working perfectly until I try to upsert it into the database. Once this line is gotten to, it throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/s3_asset_handler.py", line 187, in process_incoming_file
self.database.upsert_record(self.organisation, json_doc=data)
File "/opt/python/database_access.py", line 1218, in upsert_record
new_uuid = json_doc['uuid']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I can't seem to figure out the issue at all

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace for the exception ?

Comment: No, because you are catching the exception. could you add `print(traceback.format_exc())`  or `print(sys.exc_info()[2])` to your `except` ? You might have to import traceback and sys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get an element from a JSON object, but passing a string.

The

```py
data = json.dumps(bulk_item)
```

creates a string representing the object.

Try using `bulk_item` on it's own.

Comment: Thank you!! I have tried to expand further on your code but have ran into another (similar) error - see updated question

Comment: Please open a different question for a different problem

Comment: I thought it best to ask under this one as it is similar/related

Comment: on another note, you did not provide the stack trace information or more context for your second error

Comment: It's not providing me with any stack trace information, just the error even though I am stating ```except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())```